# Retrieving only the first email of long email threads

Tags: r, email

I am new to R and I want to retrieve only the first email received from entire email threads. Each time an email is received in the inbox, a .csv file is created (i.e. I have many files of duplicated text, just differing by newest reply that is on the top of the .csv file)

I am not sure as to how I can provide my codes to help because right now, I don't have any idea how to even start on this segment of my data cleansing.

Is there a way for me to possibly group my .csv files based on the email thread they belong to, before extracting the most duplicated text (since the first email is likely to be present in all subsequent files) to be used in my corpus for topic mining?

Or does anyone have a better way to approach this? I have considered using the threads function in tm.plugin.mail but since these are plain texts, it only returns with a depth of 1 for every email.

EDIT:

The title of the files are just random strings of alphanumerals, and I only have a metadata containing the name of the sender, the date sent (no time provided), and the title of the file that it corresponds to. Here is an idea of what my data looks like:

```
From: xxx@gmail.com

To: yyy@gmail.com

Subject: Re: xxx

Dear Sir, 

(main content) 

Yours Sincerely, 

xxx

From: yyy@gmail.com

To: xxx@gmail.com

Subject: xxx

Dear Sir, 

(main content) 

Regards, 

yyy
```

Generally, this is how the .csv file will look like (except that with each comma, there is a new line break as per .csv files), so it is actually quite messy. There is no one fixed way that the email is being formatted, so I had a failed attempt in using regex to remove everything before the last instance of "From:". Some of the emails come in another format:

```
On (date), (time), (name) <email address> wrote:
```

Comment: It would help if you gave a few examples of your .cvs files... their titles, their content, date of creating, etc.

Comment: I have just edited it to include how the data might look like, not sure if it is enough

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to have clean "conversations" regrouped in separate csv files, OR have a list of single emails that you would regroup after having them cleaned. Your regex idea might be a good one, but since the emails don't all share the same format, it makes it somewhat risky. When you say you have metadata, you are referring to what exactly? Lists in R? Would those include the title of the message?

Comment: Hmm... Not exactly. I just want to perform my topic mining only on all the first emails in my data, and not the subsequent emails that are being communicated. It is actually a separate excel sheet that has the information of my .csv files, and no, it does not include the title. But if it does, I guess it would be a lot easier.

Comment: I see. Then yes, having the title in the Excel metadata would be a big plus, as you'd be able to filter out messages having "RE: ___", among other possibilities.